# CodeIgniter don't show anything

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I now trying CodeIgniter for the first time. I created a new route rule in the `routes.php`

```
$route['ajax/rendeles/(:any)']='ajax/rendeles/$1';
$route['ajax']="ajax";
```

And a controller (`ajax.php`):

```
<?php
    class ajax extends CI_Controller{
        public function rendeles($id){
            $this->load->view("ajax/rendeles/".$id, $);
            echo $id;
        }
    }
?>
```

A view (`rendeles_view.php`):

```
<?php
$this->load->model("ajax/rendeles_model");
$result=$this->rendeles_model->rendelesReszletei($id);
foreach ($result as $row){
    echo $row->product."<br>";
}?>
```

And a model (`rendeles_model.php`):

```
<?php
class rendeles_model extends CI_Model{
    public function rendelesReszletei($id){
        $query=$this->db->get_where("_order_items", array("id_order"=>$id));
        return $query->result();
    }
}?>
```

But when I enter into the browser the `domainname/ajax/rendeles/4072` (<-this is an id of an order), but It don't show anything.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance, kukko.

Comment: You have individual views for each id? That sounds pretty strange. Also whats up with the single $ where there should be a variable to pass data to the view.

Comment: No, I haven't. I want to create a view what get the id of the order from the URL and make an SQL query and from the result of the query it makes the view for the order what you requested. Can you help me how can I do that, because It seems I did it wrong. :(

Comment: If I post the place of the files you can help more?
routes.php: root/application/config/routes.php
ajax.php: root/application/controllers/ajax.php
rendeles_view.php: root/application/views/ajax/rendeles_view.php
rendeles_model.php: root/application/models/ajax/rendeles_model.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    class ajax extends CI_Controller{
        public function rendeles($id){
            $data['id'] = $id;
            $this->load->view("ajax/rendeles", $data);
            echo $id;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I post the place of the files you can help more?

Comment: I think the controller doesn't executed, because if I write some simple echo into the controller, It write nothing to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your class names must start with an uppercase letter, like this:

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller{
    // ...

class Rendeles_model extends CI_Model{
    // ...
```

Comment: And I can refere to them with lower case first letter?